# Save and load game state in Window Game

Tags: c#, xna, load, storage

currently I' using XNA 4.0 Game Studio and the Window Game Statement Management template which is provide by Visual Studio 2010 to develop a game. Is there any suggestion about how to save and load the state of a game? Previously I've develop a window phone game and the data is stored inside IsolatedStorage. Is there any similarity for the Window Game?

```
         using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly())
            {
                using(IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = file.OpenFile("class123.xml",FileMode.Create))
                {
                    XmlWriterSettings setting = new XmlWriterSettings();
                    setting.Indent = true;
                    using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream,setting))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Student));
                        serializer.Serialize(stream,new Student(){Name = "AhLim"});
                    }

                    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Student));
                        studentA = (Student)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here's the code i recently used in Window Game Applicaiton. However, when i reach to Deserialize part, it show InvalidOperationException was unhandled and error on XML document (0,0) . May i know where's the problem?

Comment: Windows (XP/Vista/7) does have an Isolated Storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 serializer.Serialize(writer, new Student() { Name = "AhLim" });
```

instead of

```
 serializer.Serialize(stream, new Student() { Name = "AhLim" });
```

Looks like `IsolatedStorageFileStream` is using the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 3):

The code used in a Windows Phone game should work fine on PC. Data would be stored in C:\Users\\Documents\SavedGames